# squaring the product of two anticommutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a very quick and simple question but I just need clarification.

If I have the two matrices A and B that anti commute i.e. $AB=-BA$ does this mean that $(AB)^2=(BA)^2$ and therefore that $B^2A^2=A^2B^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(AB)^2 = (AB)(AB) = (-BA)(-BA) = (-1)^2(BA)^2=(BA)^2$$
so the first answer is yes.

For the second answer: $$B^2A^2 = B(BA)A = -B(AB)A = - (BA)(BA)= -(BA)^2=\\=-(AB)^2 = -A(BA)B=A(AB)B=A^2B^2$$